# Docker in host mode cannot connect to database running on host

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to get an API and several microservices up and running in docker. They need to connect to a database running outside of docker (in dev and staging it'll be running on localhost while in production it'll be on several other boxes). In order to get things set up, I have the following docker compose yaml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  api:
    image: company/api
    network_mode: "host"
  microservice-1:
    image: company/microservice-1
    network_mode: "host"
```

However, the API/microservices cannot connect to the database running locally. Additionally I cannot connect to the API from the host machine.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that my database was not accepting requests from the network IP address, instead it was accepting requests from only localhost. Switching this over to accept requests from the network IP solved the issue.